# Can I test code on android studio without run real phone or emulator?

Tags: android

Can I test code on android studio without run real phone or emulator ?

I want only test code only without UI (user interface) , For example test only :

```
Log.w("test", "a");
```

Comment: Question is vague, you need to put more details

Comment: closest answer to this that i can think of is to create a unit test

Comment: So long as you don't use any Android framework code (`Log` is Android, `System.out` is not), you can test it on the local JVM in a unit test. Or, you can stub Android framework code with Robolectric.

Comment: I mean can I print Log.w on Logcat without run real phone or emulator ?

Comment: Why would you not like to run an emulator, it's pretty easy to use, I don't see the advantages of not using an emulator?

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens probably because it's faster to just test code instead of having to wait for a build/redeploy/launch of an emulator... i often just write code in a test if I want to check something specific over having to find place to test something in my app

Comment: @a_local_nobody I agree you. I want it because It's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing Unit Tests, you can check how write unit tests with examples like https://www.journaldev.com/22674/android-unit-testing-junit4

Local Unit tests run on your computer & no emulator or device is required.

We are supposed write tests for the functionality which we have written. For classes not written by you, you can use Mocks with libs like Mockito.